# Prove the gcd $(4a + b, a + 2b) $ is equal to $1$ or $7$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So in the question it says to let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero integers such that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

So based on that I know that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and that question is basically asking if the GCD divides $7$.

So I tried to prove through the Euclidean algorithm but I think I messed up.

$a+2b = 2\times(4a+b) - 7a$

$4a+b = \frac{-4}{7}\times(-7b) +a$

$7b = 0\times a +7b$

$a = 0\times 7b +a$

$7b = 0\times a + 7b$

and so on and so on.

The fact that it is repeating tells me that I am doing something wrong.

Thanks you in advance for all of your help :)

Answer (score 7):

As you saw, we have $2(4a+b)-(a+2b)=7a$. Also, $4(a+2b)-(4a+b)=7b$.

So any common divisor of $4a+b$ and $a+2b$ is a **common divisor** of $7a$ and $7b$.

Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, there are integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=1$. It follows that $(7a)x+(7b)y=7$, so any common divisor of $7a$ and $7b$ divides $7$.

**Remark:** We have shown that if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then no positive integer *other than* $1$ or $7$ can be the gcd of $4a+b$ and $a+2b$.

Each of these can arise. For gcd equal to $1$, let $a=b=1$. For gcd equal to $7$, let $a=1$ and $b=3$.

Answer (score 2):

$7$ has a geometric interpretation here.

Take integers $u$ and $v$ such that $av-bu=1$. Then the parallelogram in $\mathbb Z^2$ defined by the vectors $(a,b)$ and $(u,v)$ has area $1$.

The linear transformation $T(x,y)= (4x + y, x + 2y)$ sends that parallelogram to another parallelogram having area $7=\det T$.

Hence $7=(4a + b)(u+2v)-(a + 2b)(4u+v)$. This proves that $\gcd(4a + b, a + 2b)$ is a divisor of $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, there are $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $ax+by=1$.
$$
\begin{align}
7
&=\overbrace{[2\color{#C00000}{(4a+b)}-\color{#00A000}{(a+2b)}]}^{\large7a}\,x+\overbrace{[4\color{#00A000}{(a+2b)}-\color{#C00000}{(4a+b)}]}^{\large7b}\,y\\[4pt]
&=(2x-y)\color{#C00000}{(4a+b)}+(4y-x)\color{#00A000}{(a+2b)}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $\gcd(4a+b,a+2b)\mid7$.

Comment: Just to ask: In this case are $2x -y$ and $4y -x$ co-primes?

Comment: @pushpen.paul: not necessarily. They might both have $7$ as a common factor. For example, given $a=1$ and $b=2$ we could pick $x=-11$ and $y=6$ to make $ax+by=1$, then $2x-y=-28$ and $4y-x=35$. However, if $\gcd(4a+b,a+2b)=7$, then $$1=(2x-y)\frac{4a+b}7+(4y-x)\frac{a+2b}7$$ implies that $\gcd(2x-y,4y-x)=1$.